# Group two Dataframes with MultiIndex columns

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have two dataframes and I would like to create a new one, which will include all the unique columns of the two source dataframes and the aggregation of the common columns.

These are two samples:

[image]

[image]

And this is the result:

[image]

All the column indexes should match in order to be aggregated.

I have written the following code:

```
df_all = pd.DataFrame
for dfColumn in df_1:
    if dfColumn in df_2.columns:
        df_all[dfColumn] = df_1.loc[:, dfColumn].add(df_2.loc[:, dfColumn])
    else:
        df_all[dfColumn] = df_1[dfColumn]

for dfColumn in df_2:
    if dfColumn not in df_all.columns:
        df_all[dfColumn] = df_2[dfColumn]
```

However, I get an error on the following line:

```
df_all[dfColumn] = df_1.loc[:, dfColumn].add(df_2.loc[:, dfColumn])
```

when I am trying to assign the value to df_all[dfColumn]

It drives me crazy all the different possibilities that you have with Python.

But I cannot find one to make it work.

Thanks for your help and time.

Answer (score 0):

Actually,

I fixed it only with the following:

```
df_all = pd.concat([df_1, df_2], axis=1)
df_all = df_all.groupby(level=[0, 1, 2], axis=1).sum()
```

Is there a way to replace `level=[0, 1, 2]` with something like `level=df_all.columns.levels` ?

Comment: Okay @Thanasis I edited my answer to do what you wanted. In this case I keep the unique columns and add the duplicated ones.